# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value' Will not change

Tags: python

```
class Dice:
    def __init__(self, sides = 6, value= None):
        self.sides = sides
        self.value = value
    def roll(self):
        self.value = randint(1, self.sides)
        return self.value
class greenDie(Dice):
  def __init__(self, sides, value):
        super().__init__(self, sides, value)
        super().__str__(self,value,faces)
  faces = {1: "", 2: "", 3: "", 
             4:"", 5:"", 6:""}
```

Later call

I keep on getting the error "**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'" no matter what changes I have made. I have looked at similar problems and tried to use their methods to fix my own, but they never work.

Comment: Remove the self inside super - super(sides, value)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicit pass `self` while calling the class methods.

It should be:

```
super().__init__(sides, value)
```

Comment: sadly I still get the same error message.

Comment: did you do the same for `__str__` method as well?

Comment: yes, my program is supposed to simulate the dice game of Zombie, with different colored die. So when I call on the greenDie method in another class, written like "runGreen= greenDie(Dice)" it fails to recognize the 'value'

Comment: you shouldn't call like `runGreen= greenDie(Dice)`, it should be `runGreen= greenDie(sides, value)`

Comment: you need to initialize the `sides` and `values` to something before passing or you can directly pass the values in a hard-coded manner as `runGreen= greenDie(6, 6)`

Comment: hard coding does get rid of the missing arguments for the greenDie function, however now it gives the error 

   <ipython-input-4-3731850851b2> in __init__(self, sides, value)
     20   def __init__(self, sides, value):
     21         super().__init__(sides, value)
---> 22         super().__str__(sides, value)
     23   faces = {1: "", 2: "", 3: "", 
     24              4:"", 5:"", 6:""}

TypeError: expected 0 arguments, got 2

Comment: check your `Dice` class `__str__` method, it is probably not taking any attributes but you are passing two so that's why you get the error. I would suggest to first go through the basics of the concepts (https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) and then try to apply them in implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Should be like below

```
    super().__init__(sides, value)
```